# Why does this occurs?

Tags: mysql

```
create trigger after_user_register 
before INSERT on Users 
for EACH ROW 
begin 
declare @id integer;
declare @userName varchar(30);
declare @userSurname varchar(30);
select
  @id = userId,
  @userName = userName,
  @userSurname = userSurname
from
  inserted;
insert into
  UsersFullName
values(DEFAULT, @id, concat(@userName, @userSurname)) end
```

I'm getting #1064 error for the first declaration. Can you help me removing this error.

Comment: Can you please share the full text of the error?

Comment: Declare needs to be without @ SET uses @ so your are mixing here.. also iam not sure what you are trying to do here because the other code is also wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues with your [`CREATE TRIGGER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html). You can use the following simpler solution:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER after_user_register 
AFTER INSERT on Users 
FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO UsersFullName (id, fullname) 
      SELECT new.userId, CONCAT(new.userName, new.userSurname); 
  END 
//

DELIMITER ;
```

> **demo:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bE5DN43hjX7TtSpS3GDNRn/0

Comment: it works. Thank you first. However, Delimiter made me confuse. What is its functionality?

Comment: It changes the delimiter from `;` to `//` so you can use the `CREATE TRIGGER` within a script. In case you don't change the delimiter mysql detects the end of the `CREATE TRIGGER` after the `INSERT` command.